# afl-gcc-fast make Fail missing separator error

Tags: c++, fuzzer

when I use AFL++ to compile my project.

`CC=*****/afl-gcc-fast CXX=****/afl-g++-fast make myproject`

I get the error:

some.d:1 *** missing separator. Stop

And I open the some.d file:

```
[0;36mafl-gcc-pass [1;97m++4.08a[0m by <oliva@adacore.com>
[1;94m[*] [0mInline instrumentation at ratio of 100% in non-hardened mode.[0m
XXXX.o XXXX.d : XXXX.cpp 
...
```

there is a "include some.d" in makefile.
but I think the some.d is create by afl-g++-fast ?

So why this happens ,and How can I fix it?thanks

My demo project works well(build by alf++ ,run well), but when I build real project, I got this error.

Comment: "Missing separator" is typical when your makefile doesn't have tabs for the indentation, but spaces instead.

Comment: Those first two lines *should not be there*. You should figure out how they got there or, alternatively, remove the use of `-MMF` and `-MMD` flags from your makefile

Comment: You will need to show your Makefile. Is it possibly using `-M` or `-MD` and redirecting the output using `>` ? That should be changed to use an explicit `-MF` argument.

Comment: yes,looks like it's build script write to the .d file.
I will remove them all, and create a clean build.

Comment: @Botje I can confirm it's because the script use
 $(CPP) -MM &< and output to the .d file.

but if use AFL++ to build ,it's always out put:

```

Comment: Edit your question with the additional information.

Comment: More specifically show your Makefile or "the script" . Like I asked two months ago.

Comment: @Botje 
yes ,the root cause is the AFL++ will print some data like "[0;36mafl-gcc-pass [1;97m++4.08a[0m by <oliva@adacore.com>" in the screen,
and the makefile script use -MM
then use the output redirect to the next script by "|".
at last ,the .d have the extra tag.

I use the -MM -MF to genetate a  temp file
then redirect the temp file for next step.
the error has fix.
Thanks.

Comment: Great! Suggest you write this as a self-answer so others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

the root cause is:
the AFL++ will print some data like

```
 "[0;36mafl-gcc-pass [1;97m++4.08a[0m by <oliva@adacore.com>"
```

in the screen, and the makefile script use -MM then use the output redirect to the next script by "|". at last ,the .d have the extra tag.

Fix:

I use the -MM -MF to genetate a temp file then redirect the temp file for next step. the error has fix.

thanks Botje's answer.